# "Ok Google" voice action bugs - Reminder voice action gives me a Google search

Tags: nexus-5, google-now, ok-google

Ok, so here're my issues with "Ok Google" on the Nexus 5:

1. When I say - "Ok Google" Remind me to call XYZ at Work, the reminder page does not pop up. It does a Google search. On the other hand, if I say "Ok Google" Remind me to charge phone when I reach home, the reminder page pops up. I have both my home and work addresses listed and I have no clue as to why this is happening.
2. When I say "Ok Google, Call (name)", it only dials if it's an old contact. So if I add a new contact, Google says "Please choose contact".
3. When I Say "Ok Google, note to self" it recognizes but it does not store as a note.

Could any of you help me with the same, please?

Comment: I tried it now, the first one does do a google search.

The second one, I go it working. Create the new contact, try to search for it my typing the name. Then if you try it will call.
The third one does work, it will create an empty note but will not save it untill you do it manually.